# JSON serialize a PlaceholderField CKEditor for JsonResponse

Tags: json, django, django-cms

I've got a Django CMS app which I've updated to use a `PlaceholderField` in place of an `HTMLField` in order to enable the use of the CMS plugins within the app, with nested plugins etc.

The `PlaceholderField` is limited to only allow the `TextPlugin` and the app has a javascript feature to poll the database for new objects & load them in via Ajax.

How do you serialize the `TextPlugin` within the `PlaceholderField`? I'm currently building the response data like so;

```
    data = []
    for item in items:
        data.append({
            'id': item.pk,
            'title': item.title,
            'body': (
                'News body. This is a placeholder field. We need to figure '
                'out how to serialize this.'
            ),
            'dt_created': item.dt_created,
            'tz_created': item.tz_created
        })
    extra = {
        'data': data,
    }

    data = json.dumps(extra)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Placeholder.render`](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/3698648e9a3e76e71d88a7b0bd34a8667b1ae4e0/cms/models/placeholdermodel.py#L126), but be aware that `context` must have a valid `request` object.